# Create new rows of data based on range of dates in another table

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a table that contains a start date, an end date, and number of hours. I would like to create rows of data in a new table based on these values.

| ID | StartDate | EndDate | Hours |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3/2022 | 6/2022 | 40 |
| 2 | 4/2022 | 4/2023 | 144 |

What I would like do is create a table that evenly splits the hours over the date range.

| ForeignKey | MonthYear | Hours |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3/2022 | 10 |
| 1 | 4/2022 | 10 |
| 1 | 5/2022 | 10 |
| 1 | 6/2022 | 10 |
| 2 | 4/2022 | 12 |
| 2 | 5/2022 | 12 |
| 2 | 6/2022 | 12 |
| 2 | 7/2022 | 12 |
| 2 | 8/2022 | 12 |
| 2 | 9/2022 | 12 |
| 2 | 10/2022 | 12 |
| 2 | 11/2022 | 12 |
| 2 | 12/2022 | 12 |
| 2 | 1/2023 | 12 |
| 2 | 2/2023 | 12 |
| 2 | 3/2023 | 12 |
| 2 | 4/2023 | 12 |

I have seen examples on how to do this using CTEs but they are not available in MS Access. I am trying to find a way to do this without VBA if possible. If necessary I will resort to VBA.

Comment: Why does output show two 4/2022 records for ID 2? I don't think can accomplish without VBA. Open recordset, loop and write records to 'temp' table.

Comment: StartDate and EndDate should be full dates to simplify calculating number of months: `SELECT ID, StartDate, EndDate, DateDiff("m",[StartDate],[EndDate])+1 AS Months, Hours
FROM Data;`. Otherwise, do a calc  to modify the "dates" to actual dates - will involve string manipulation.

Comment: The double entry of 4/2022 for ID 2 was a typo. I corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is VBA to get you started. It uses table with date/time type fields holding a full date value:

```
Sub ExpandData()
Dim db As DAO.Database, rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim dteStartDate As Date, dteEndDate As Date, x As Integer, intMonths As Integer
Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT ID, StartDate, EndDate, DateDiff('m',[StartDate],[EndDate])+1 AS Months, Hours FROM Data;")
db.Execute "DELETE FROM DataExpanded"
Do While Not rs.EOF
    For x = 0 To rs!Months - 1
        db.Execute "INSERT INTO DataExpanded(ForeignKey, MonthDayYear, Hours) " & _
                    "VALUES(" & rs!ID & "," & DateAdd("m", x, rs!startDate) & "," & rs!Hours / rs!Months & ")"
    Next
    rs.MoveNext
Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with SQL using a *Cartesian* (multiplying) query (where `Hours` is your source table):

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT 
    Hours.ID, 
    DateAdd("m",10*Abs([Deca].[id] Mod 10)+Abs([Uno].[id] Mod 10),[StartDate]) AS MonthYear, 
    [Hours]/(1+DateDiff("m",[StartDate],[EndDate])) AS HoursPerMonth
FROM 
    MSysObjects AS Uno, 
    MSysObjects AS Deca, 
    Hours
WHERE 
    DateAdd("m",10*Abs([Deca].[id] Mod 10)+Abs([Uno].[id] Mod 10),[StartDate])<=[EndDate];
```

The output will be different from your expected output, as you for ID 2 think you have 12 months, but do have 13:

[image]

Comment: Exactly what I was trying to do before resorting to VBA. However, because of Cartesian association of tables, it might perform so slowly with large dataset that VBA could be faster.